# Using Makefile variable before definition in included file

Tags: makefile

I've encountered a little problem during my Makefile learning adventure.
I have prepared two scripts. The first one is the main *Makefile*:

```
all:
        @echo $(COMPONENTNAME)

include ~/Projects/tests/mk
```

And here's the *mk* file

```
COMPONENTNAME:=ISeeYou
```

Now, when I run

```
make all
```

I get

```
ISeeYou
```

I am not sure why... I was convinced that a variable must be defined before it is used. And the include is after COMPONENTNAME is being used. My suspicion is that all of the includes are done first, and then the target creation is started. Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

> My suspicion is that all of the includes are done first, and then the target creation is started.

Yes, you are right.

All global sections in Makefile should be completely parsed before make is able to decide, which targets(and in which order) should be built. Target's recipes are evaluated only when it is needed to build target. This is explicitely stated in [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Variables-in-Recipes.html):

> The other way in which make processes recipes is by expanding any variable references in them. This occurs after make has finished reading all the makefiles and the target is determined to be out of date; so, the recipes for targets which are not rebuilt are never expanded.